# ¿Cómo conectar barra de progreso con QThread en PyQT5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

He estado intentado pasar el proceso de descarga para los audios de Youtube en un hilo diferente utilizando la librería pafy. Con esta librería se puede utilizar un método llamado "mycb" donde es posible obtener los kbs descargados y los totales para establecer una barra de progreso. 
Aquí les muestro lo que intento hacer mediante la clase QThread

```
from audio import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog,QFileDialog, QMessageBox,QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import getpass, glob, pafy

class DownloadAudio(QThread):
    signal_recvd = pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_total = pyqtSignal(int)
    def download(self, ruta, url):
        ruta = ruta
        url = url
        video = pafy.new(url)
        title = video.title
        duration = video.duration
        dwn = video.getbestaudio()
        dwn.download(filepath=ruta, callback=self.mycb, meta=True)

    def mycb(self,total, recvd, ratio, rate,eta): #Método de la librería Pafy para saber los kbs recibidos y los totales (con este me apoyo para establecer la barra de progreso)
        self.signal_total.emit(total)
        self.signal_recvd.emit(recvd)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(920,700)
        self.txt_ruta.setText("/home/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Música")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 350)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 350) 
        self.btn_descargar.clicked.connect(self.download_audio)
        self.btn_destino.clicked.connect(self.ruta)
    def download_audio(self):
        ruta = self.txt_ruta.text()
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        url = self.txt_url.text()
        video = pafy.new(url)
        title = video.title
        duration = video.duration
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem(title))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem(duration))
        self.calc = DownloadAudio()
        self.calc.download(ruta,url)
        self.calc.signal_recvd.connect(self.progress)
    def progress(self,value):
        self.progressBar.setValue(value)

    def ruta(self):
        path = os.path.normpath(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self))
        self.txt_ruta.setText(path)                 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Con este código el proceso funciona aunque no correctamente ni mucho menos puedo establecer la barra de progreso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario heredar de QThread, debes crear un QObject que viva en otro hilo e invocar al slot usando `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)`:

```py
import os
from audio import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import pafy
from functools import partial


class DownloadAudio(QtCore.QObject):
    signal_recvd = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_total = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_info = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def download(self, ruta, url):
        video = pafy.new(url)
        title = video.title
        duration = video.duration
        self.signal_info.emit(title, duration)
        video = pafy.new(url)
        title = video.title
        duration = video.duration
        dwn = video.getbestaudio()
        dwn.download(filepath=ruta, callback=self.mycb, meta=True)

    # Método de la librería Pafy para saber los kbs recibidos y
    # los totales (con este me apoyo para establecer la barra de progreso)
    def mycb(self, total, recvd, ratio, rate, eta):
        self.signal_total.emit(total)
        self.signal_recvd.emit(recvd)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(920,700)
        music_path = QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation(
            QtCore.QStandardPaths.MusicLocation
        )
        self.txt_ruta.setText(os.path.normpath(music_path))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 350)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 350)
        self.btn_descargar.clicked.connect(self.download_audio)
        self.btn_destino.clicked.connect(self.ruta)
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)

        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()
        self.calc = DownloadAudio()
        self.calc.moveToThread(thread)
        self.calc.signal_recvd.connect(self.progressBar.setValue)
        self.calc.signal_total.connect(self.progressBar.setMaximum)
        self.calc.signal_info.connect(self.append_row)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

    def download_audio(self):
        ruta = self.txt_ruta.text()
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        url = self.txt_url.text()
        if url:
            wrapper = partial(self.calc.download, ruta, url)
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def append_row(self, title, duration):
        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(title))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(duration))

    def ruta(self):
        path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
        if path:
            self.txt_ruta.setText(os.path.normpath(path))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Gracias, es perfecto incluso mejor! agradezco de antemano donde poder encontrar documentación sobre QObject y QTimer.singleShot(0, ...):

Comment: @ErickCasanOva Sobre la técnica de usar QObject en otro hilo puedes leerlo en https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

Comment: @ErickCasanOva y en el caso de QTimer.singleShot(0, ...) se deduce de la docs ya que indica que el slot sera invocado en el hilo donde vive el receptor ya que segun la docs el tipo de conexión por defecto es de Qt::AutoConnection, y en concecuencia usa la conexión de tipo Qt::QueuedConnection que señala eso. Lee https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads